# Build an APEX URL that pulls in the APP_USER ID

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using a PL/SQL Region in APEX where I am build an Interactive Report Link that will filter the report for the USERs :APP_USER id and provide them a view of their rows only.

The Region first counts the rows to show the user how many rows he/she has and then the URL directs them to the IR page and filters the IR for their ID.  For example...

```
SELECT count(*) INTO l_open_proj  FROM crd_mpl_upload WHERE LOWER(GLB_CPM_QID) = LOWER(:APP_USER);
```

later...I have the part where the URL is built.

```
sys.htp.p('<li class="uNumber uGrid col_2">');    
sys.htp.p('<ahref="'||sys.htf.escape_sc('fp='||:APP_ID||':12:'||:APP_SESSION||':::12,RIR:**IR_GLB_CPM_QID:upper(:APP_USER)**:') ||'">');
sys.htp.p('<big class="uValue">' || l_open_proj || '</big>');
sys.htp.p('<small class="uLabel">My Projects</small>');
sys.htp.p('</a>');
sys.htp.p('</li>');
```

The part specifically I am having issues with is the **IR_GLB_CPM_QID:upper(:APP_USER)** as :APP_USER here does not pull through the users NTLM authenticated ID.  I ahve tried upper and lower, etc. and I don;t that is the issues.  The ID will come through as P123456 for example.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What a you doing? What is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to the :APP_USER bind variable is within a string, unlike the others.

In this case it's safe to user `&APP_USER.` instead (don't forget trailing dot), but do not use this substitution syntax in SQL.

You'll also have issues with the upper() in this context, though I don't think it's necessary? And should be done within the SQL if so.

Comment: Thank so much for your time in answering.  I think I am close as I am getting the user id in the URL, but the IR is not filtering for the id for some reason.  Can you look at the syntax and see if I have missed something?  href="'|| sys.htf.escape_sc('f?
p='||:APP_ID||':12:'||:APP_SESSION||':::12,RIR:IR_PMA_QID:&APP_USER.:') ||'">');

Comment: So there is a column alias of PMA_QID in your IR? This syntax seems ok for 4.x but it may have changed for 5 since more than one IR per page is possible. What version are you on? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/bldapp_rpt_int.htm#HTMDB25372

Comment: Hi, we are on 4.x right now.  The column alias is PMA_QID exactly and the correct ID shows if I hover of the link but once click the report is not filtered.

Comment: Can you supply the generated URL, from the f?p onwards

Comment: sys.htp.p('<li class="uNumber uGrid col_2">');
    sys.htp.p('<a href="'|| sys.htf.escape_sc('f?
p='||:APP_ID||':12:'||:APP_SESSION||':::12,RIR:IR_(PMA_QID):&APP_USER.:') ||'">');
    sys.htp.p('<big class="uValue">' || l_open_proj || '</big>');
    sys.htp.p('<small class="uLabel">My Projects</small>');
    sys.htp.p('</a>');
    sys.htp.p('</li>');

Comment: The space after the question mark may be SO formatting, but I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be brackets around IR_PMA_QID.
sys.htf.escape_sc('f?p='||:APP_ID||':12:'||:APP_SESSION||':::12,RIR:IR_PMA_QID:&APP_USER.:') ||'">');

Comment: Wow..totally missed that!  Thanks so much